# Gstreamer Analog Video Capturing

Tags: image-processing, gstreamer, image-capture

I am using Sensoray Model-1012 frame grabber.
First of all my setup is getting a screen output from HDMI and convert it to NTSC CVBS output. I am getting screen video to Toradex IM8 CPU via model-1012.

My problem is, when there is something moving horizontally on the screen it gets sketched from corners. I am loading an example video. It doesn't occur when I connect analog video to my JVC display.

I am using Gstreamer as a software and here is my pipeline:

```
GST_DEBUG=3 gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video6 ! 'video/x-raw, format=(string)UYVY, width=720, height=480, framerate=30/1' ! interlace field-pattern=2 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

[image: Görüntü]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem should be related to the "interlace" module. You can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlaced_video#Interlacing_problems) a description of interlacing. Basically half of the lines of your image are from a previous frame, and when something moves in the scene it looks weird, like ghosted. You should be able to solve simply removing interlace

```
GST_DEBUG=3 gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video6 ! 'video/x-raw, format=(string)UYVY, width=720, height=480, framerate=30/1' ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```